# Q:Find the volume of the set of all (x, y, z) which satisfy: 2x − 2y − 2z − 2 ≤ x 2 + y 2 + z 2 ≤ 2x − 2y + 2z + 13

Tags: calculus

**Question**

> Find the volume of the set of all $(x, y, z)$ which satisfy: 
>   $$
> 2x − 2y − 2z − 2 ≤ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ≤ 2x − 2y + 2z + 13
> $$

I have this question on my Calculus 2 homework.
This subject has not been discussed in my lectures. So I do not know how to get started and tackle this problem.
The textbook I have access to is James Stewart-Calculus_ Early transcendentals-Brooks Cole (2016).

I someone could tell me how I tackle this problem, it would be greatly appreciated!

With kind regards,

Comment: I edited your question, would you check if I didn´t do anything funky?

Comment: Thank you for editing, everything is fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break it down to two inequalities, their conjunction to be precise:

$$2x-2y-2z-2 \leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \text{  and  } x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 2x-2y+2z+13$$

The first inequality can be written as
$$x^2-2x+y^2+2y+z^2+2z+2\geq 0$$

Now just complete the squares

$$x^2-2x+1+y^2+2y+1+z^2+2z+1\geq1$$

or,
$$(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2+(z+1)^2 \geq1 \tag{1}$$

Do the same for the second inequality, and you will arrive at

$$(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2+(z-1)^2 \leq 16 \tag{2}$$

Notice that $(1)$ represents the exterior of a sphere centered at $(1,-1,-1)$ with radius $1$, and $(2)$ is the interior of a sphere centered at $(1,-1,1)$ with radius 4, including boundary points. Consider the balls represented by the inequalities
$$(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2+(z+1)^2 \leq 1$$
$$(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2+(z-1)^2 \leq 16$$
A quick sketch will show that the second ball completely contains the first one. So, the volume of interest is the "space" between the inner ball and the outer ball, and it can be obtained by subtracting the volume of the inner ball from the volume of the outer ball.

Recall that the volume of a ball is 
$$V = \frac{4}{3}r^3\pi$$
where $r$ is the radius.